# Is there any way to get a "function list" in the new VS2015 Diagnostic Tools like there was in the old (slow) Instrumentation diagnostics?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, instrumentation, debug-diagnostic-tool, diagnostic-tools

I liked the function list because I could see which functions were using the most CPU overall, but instrumentation is slow. Is there any way I can get that feature in the new diagnostic tools, or at least export a report so I can analyze it as needed? My program runs extremely slowly during instrumentation (though it didn't always do that; I'm not sure what changed), and it would be nice to be able to collect the data using diagnostic tools, even if I can't view it there.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the "old" diagnostics tools are still in VS 2015. To run it select *Debug ->  Start Diagnostic Tools Without Debugging* and then check *Performance Wizard*. Or select *Debug -> Profiler -> Performance Explorer -> New Performance Session*.

Besides, the "old" diagnostics tools do not have to be slow. You are right that in general the instrumentation is slow but you can also use the sampling. You can do so on the first page of *Performance Wizard*. It is even a default option.

As to the "new" diagnostics tools. I assume that you are talking about [CPU Usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn971856.aspx). You also have the "function list" there. See the below image (downloaded from already mentioned article [CPU Usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn971856.aspx)).

[image]

Comment: I'm aware of the old tools being present in VS2015, but of course instrumentation is slow, and I find that sampling is still somewhat slow (to analyze data - it's OK just running my app). I've also had trouble on occasion getting instrumentation and sampling to report on functions outside the startup project (e.g. in referenced library projects that I actually want to profile - who needs to profile a GUI all that often?)

Comment: As for the new tools, there is no function list, only a tree, so if I want to see what functions are using the most CPU, I have to drill down to every instance of each function I suspect to use a lot of CPU in the call stack. Fortunately the next version of Visual Studio will support the feature I'm looking for: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs15-relnotes#debuggingdiag